# Semigroup ideals of a ring or an algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $R$ be a ring or an algebra. Suppose $B\subseteq R$ satisfies the property $BR \subseteq B$ and $RB\subseteq B$. Is there a general theory of subsets with this property in a ring (resp. algebra) akin to the theory of ideals?

---

*Note:* One can simply forget the additive structure (resp. vector space structure) and consider $R$ as a semigroup with multiplication. In that case, $B$ is a semigroup ideal of $R$. I wonder whether there is a theory that takes into account the addition (resp. the vector space structure) of $R$, as well?

For example, let's say $B$ generates the ring, resp. $B$ spans the algebra. What more can be said about $B$, beyond what the semigroup theory provides?

Any references would be well appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that this is just saying that $B$ is a sub-bi-$R$-module of $R$.  EDIT:  Oh, you're not assuming that $B$ is closed under addition.  In that case, as you say, it seems that the additive structure of $R$ is playing no role, so this is really a question about semigroups.

Comment: You may want to read about "multiplicative ideal theory". In particular, I would recommend to look at Halter-Koch's book on ideal systems.

Comment: [Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4302350/29335)

Comment: @SalvoTringali Thank you for your reply and for the book reference.

Comment: Let me point out for a simple ring every nonzero semigroup ideal spans the algebra but it is not usually the case that the converse holds.  The converse holds for division rings and purely infinite simple rings.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thank you for your kind reply. Do I understand the converse correctly: "if every nonzero semigroup ideal spans the algebra R, then R is simple" ? I doubt it, since the sets of the form $RxR$, for some $x\in R$, are semigroup ideals of R that span principal ideals. Thus, R possess no nontrivial principal ideals, so it must be simple. On the other hand, clearly not all spanning sets can be semigroup ideals. Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: No I meant for a simple ring a being 0-simple as a semigruop is equivalent to being a division ring or purely infinite.

Comment: Just to add the reference: "Let $R$ be a simple ring that is not a division ring. Then, $R$ is purely infinite if and only if $RxR=R$ for all nonzero $x\in R$ if and only if $R$ is $0$-simple as a semigroup."
http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1016358107918